# Default <files ".ht*"> doesn't work, but <files '^.ht'> does

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I was able to download my `.htaccess` file despite `httpd.conf` contains the following lines.

```
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

When I changed it to this, it works as expected.

```
<Files '^.ht'>
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Is there a syntax issue I'm not seeing?

Comment: The problem might be that some "more advanced" editors and word processors will attempt to use text book style typesetting/formatting for "code" and when you use the neutral `" "` double [quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) as found on your keyboard , such editors can change those to the left/right double quotation marks `“  ”` which you would use for citing text. That also happens sometimes when copying online examples.

Comment: The second example (the one you say worked) is not meaninful for Apache 2.4 - to enable a regular expression you'd need `<Files ~ '^.ht'>` or `<FilesMatch '^\.ht'>` (which is already included in standard Apache builds). But also your original should already work. Are you sure your config is being applied to the running instance of Apache?